# Get latest post and then other posts in a loop - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to get the last post then other posts from a specific category. This the code i got so far: 
[CHECK THE DESIGN >>HERE<<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKs0Y.png)

```html
<?php 

$args = array(
     'cat' => 140, // Category ID
     'posts_per_page' => 10
 );
 $modone_qry = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $modone_qry->have_posts() ) : while ( $modone_qry->have_posts() ) : $modone_qry->the_post(); ?>




    <?php if ($modone_qry->post_count === 1): ?>

        <div class="one-post"><h1> LATEST POST HERE </h1></div>

    <?php else: ?>

        <div class="multi-post"><h1>OTHERS POSTS HERE</h1></div>

    <?php endif; ?>



<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: It still loops all post not the first one then others

Comment: Please check the design reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKs0Y.png

Comment: As @AlivetoDie mentioned in answer below, you need to deal it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Autista_z, the working code:

```html
    <?php 

    $args = array(
     'cat' => 140, // Category ID
     'posts_per_page' => 10
     );
     $modone_qry = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <?php $post_number = 0; ?>

    <?php if ( $modone_qry->have_posts() ) : while ( $modone_qry->have_posts() ) : $modone_qry->the_post(); ?>

    <?php $post_number++; ?>

    <?php if ($post_number === 1): ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?> BIG</h1>

    <?php else: ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?> SMALL</h1>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know wordpress, but with simple php you can do it like this

```
<?php 

$args = array(
 'cat' => 140, // Category ID
 'posts_per_page' => 10
 );
 $modone_qry = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php $post_number = 0; ?>

<?php if ( $modone_qry->have_posts() ) : while ( $modone_qry->have_posts() ) : $modone_qry->the_post(); ?>

<?php $post_number++; ?>

<?php if ($post_number === 1): ?>

    <!-- HTML of latest post - First in loop -->

<?php else: ?>

    <!-- HTML of others posts -->

<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: If you look at the design, I think Eiad wants loop of the articles, where the first is in design bigger, and others smaller. And the "stupid" way to do it, is what i wrote.

Comment: @ Autista_z you're right, also Can you please help with more details? where the HTML of latest post and where is the other post loop?  Please check the design here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKs0Y.png

Comment: @Autista_z You're a star, Thanks alot that really made my day. just a little thing is i added <?php ?> around $post_number++;  and all worked like charm.